# anydesk: error while loading shared libraries libbrcmglesv2.so

Tags: debian

After installed anydesk_6.0.1-1_armhf.deb I clicked internet->anydesk but nothing happened, so I use command
`#/usr/bin/anydesk`

> anydesk: error while loading shared libraries libbrcmGLESv2

`#ln -s /opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so /opt/vc/lib/libbrcmGLESv2.so`

I soft linked it still have the same error.

Comment: Are you using bullseye? It is told in [link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/133499/anydesk-on-bullseye?noredirect=1#comment227373_133499)  here libbrcmGLESv2 is not available on bullseye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `sudo apt-get install libraspberrypi0`, like someone suggested here ([link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=186255#p1206310))

Comment: It does not work for me

Answer (score 10):

The following trick will do it:

```
sudo apt install libgles-dev libegl-dev
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so /usr/lib/libbrcmGLESv2.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so /usr/lib/libbrcmEGL.so
```

Tested with stock RaspiOS Bullseye and anydesk repository.

Comment: DL1MX I have tried it and get following error: failed to create symbolic link '/opt/vc/lib/libbrcmGLESv2.so': No such file or directory

Comment: Oh, sorry. Wrong target path. Corrected.

Comment: Thank you, using Raspbian 11 (debian/bullseye) and anydesk_6.2.1-1_armhf.deb this hint worked to start anydesk service. (before I had to `apt install libegl1-mesa` to install anydesk)

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `sudo ldconfig` after adding a library symlink, otherwise the linker will not know about it. The linker will not scan the entire filesystem every time you run a command (that would be too slow), it relies on a library cache created by `ldconfig`.

Comment: This one also does not work on me.

Comment: @HakanUlusoy I didn't say it would work. I said a simple symlink couldn't possibly work without running `ldconfig` first.

Answer (score 1):

DL1MX really help me to install the anydesk armhf on Raspbian 64 aarch64, my steps:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf

sudo apt install libpolkit-gobject-1-0:armhf libraspberrypi0:armhf libraspberrypi-dev:armhf libraspberrypi-bin:armhf libgles-dev:armhf libegl-dev:armhf

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so /usr/lib/libbrcmGLESv2.so

sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so /usr/lib/libbrcmEGL.so
```

Then download the installer and install

Comment: This one is good answer and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

If you have another rPI with /opt/vc you can copy that over and also copy over /etc/ld.so.conf.d/00-vmcs.conf (or create it with the text "/opt/vc/lib")

then run 'ldconfig'

Now Anydesk worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chromium-Browser libs also.

```
ln -s /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libGLESv2.so /usr/lib/libbrcmGLESv2.so
```

and

```
ln -s /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libEGL.so /usr/lib/libEGL.so
```

For me, worked like a charm.