# anydesk on bullseye

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

Is there anyone who can install and use anydesk on bullseye?
I install it with debian package but I am getting

```
anydesk: error while loading shared libraries: libbrcmGLESv2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

error.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libraspberrypi0
```

Didnt work.

Probably duplicate of this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/116996/anydesk-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libbrcmglesv2-so)

Comment: `libbrcmGLESv2` isn't available in bullseye

Comment: Very bad news. Do you have any suggestion to install anydesk?

Comment: install raspberry pi buster - https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_armhf/images/raspios_armhf-2021-05-28/ or the lite version https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_armhf/images/raspios_lite_armhf-2021-05-28/

Answer (score 0):

It seems rbpi Os 11 bullseye is not supported for the moment.
https://support.anydesk.com/knowledge/supported-operating-systems

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/123357)

Answer (score 0):

Last time I tried, the official link from the official anydesk website did not install on Raspian (the most current at the time, 4 months ago), really don't remember the error now.

I then found this link https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-anydesk/ with another source and method, which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer that works for me. 'DL1MX' has provide the solution that solved the problem in my environment:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/133496/155685

```
sudo apt install libgles-dev libegl-dev
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libGLESv2.so /usr/lib/libbrcmGLESv2.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libEGL.so /usr/lib/libbrcmEGL.so
```

I know it is an old post. But if this still an issue in your pi, may be you can give it a try. :)